# Trying to load private key in js file causes page to fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js, ganache

I am trying to run a html webpage that will load information into a Ganache blockchain. I've an app.js file that works when I run with the command *node app.js*.
However when I try and run the app.js off the html page with  at the bottom the html page stops loading.

It seems to happen when I'm using the Buffer command e.g.

*const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('d39f96797d2e190eaf3d2c0ecfca1446178b21e83cb23222621761d2cf44ba7c', 'hex')*

Does anyone know how to pass the private key into the app.js file as Buffer might be restricted to node.js?

p.s. the private key is a test one created with Ganache

Comment: There is no `Buffer` object in a web browser, thus `Buffer.from()` will fail in a browser.  That exists only in node.js.  What does "run the app.js off the html page" mean?

Comment: Poor structuring of sentance. I meant called by <script src="app.js"></script>. I guess I'll need to find another way to work around the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you can't run that code in the browser and you shouldn't be passing the privateKey to the browser code anyway.